# How to update ALL requests when a request property has changed, when using Async/Await?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await, task

I'm using async/await to make multiple requests per second to a service using their API. The problem I am running into is when I need to refresh the token (it expries every hour). After the token has expired, I get a 401 unauthorized error back from the service.  That's when I refresh the token, and retry the failed request again. The token gets refreshed fine, but what I'm finding is that even after the token is refreshed, a lot of subsequent requests are still sent with the old token. Following are the methods that are used in this functionality. Wondering if anything standouts as being the culprit for this unintended behavior.

```
public void Process(id)
{
    var tasks = items.Select(async item =>
    {
        var response = await SendRequestAsync(() => CreateRequest(item.Url));
        //do something with response
        await Process(item.subId); //recursive call to process sub items.
    }).ToList();

    if (tasks.Any())
        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);      

}

public HttpRequestMessage CreateRequest(string url)
{
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url);
    request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + AppSettings.AccessToken); 
    return request;
}

public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendRequestAsync(Func<HttpRequestMessage> funcReq)
{   
    var response = await ExecuteRequestAsync(funcReq());

    while (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
    {
        await RefreshTokenAsync();
        return await ExecuteRequestAsync(funcReq());  //assuming func ensures that CreateRequest is called each time, so I'll always have a new request with the updated token.
    }  

    return response;            
}

private async Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteRequestAsync(HttpRequestMessage request)
{
    var client = new HttpClient();
    var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
    return response;    
}

public async Task RefreshTokenAsync()
{
    await semaphoreSlim.WaitAsync();
    try
    {      
        if ((DateTime.Now - refreshTime).TotalMinutes < 60) //tokens last for an hour, so after the refresh is made by the first request that failed, subsequent requests should have the latest token.
            return; 

        Token newToken = GetNewToken();
        AppSettings.AccessToken = newToken.AccessToken //AppSettings is a singleton wrapper class for app.cofig app settings
        refreshTime = DateTime.Now
    }
    finally
    {
        semaphoreSlim.Release();
    }
}
```

Comment: How much longer are requests being executed with the same token? Have you eliminated the possibility that those are requests which were in progress/started before the token was refreshed?

Comment: @MarcelN. At first I get a bunch of 401 errors--that's expected. But my semaphore should ensure that only the first failed request will refresh the token. The remaining ones should then have the updated token by the time they are sent out.  Though some requests do go out with the new token, a lot of requests are still going out with the old one. Some retry requests are going with the old token for more than an hour after the refresh.

Comment: How long do your requests take? It sounds very reasonable to assume what @MarcelN said about previous requests not finishing execution. Also, how are you initalizing your `SemaphoreSlim`?

Comment: I don't think that's entirely true. Some requests may already be at this point `var response = await ExecuteRequestAsync(funcReq());`, after `funcReq` evaluated, when the token gets refreshed. By this time it's too late for them to get the new token. They will get executed with the old one.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov But for any given request, I can expect that the second time that same request is sent out, that they should have the latest token, right?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov new SemaphoreSlim(1) in the constructor.

Comment: @MarcelN. You're right, but that just means that several of my requests will have the old token when they are fired for the first time.  But when a request fails, they have to go through the RefreshToken routine and should have the updated token when they are sent out the second time right? My concern is only for retry requests to have the updated token.

Comment: @Prabhu: Agreed, but I am not sure if there's any proof there are requests that execute one or more times with the same token. That would mean this `() => CreateRequest(item.Url)` is cached, which cannot happen.

Comment: Have you debugged requests that go through `RefreshTokenAsync` and still get the old token? Also, why are you using a `Func<HttpWebResponse>` instead of simply calling `CreateRequest` yourself?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov the CreateRequest is actually in a different class, I just simplified it for the discussion here, so in my real case I use funcs so I can invoke it back from the called class. As for debugging, I can't seem to isolate the issue. It seems to work as expected when debugging. But I think I'll have to try again. I did try probing the value of AppSettings.AccessToken just before client.SendAsync, and it is always the latest token.

Comment: Have you maybe considered a locking mechanism during your update of the token? So all other callers will have to wait for the updated token and cant proceed until then?

Comment: @MarcelN. So anyhow do I have the right approach? Is there a better way to handle the token refresh and hand over the new token to all subsequent requests?  Is there a way to easily update the request header for all pending requests?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Isn't the semaphore in the RefreshTokenAsync method  enough to ensure exclusive/serial access? Since this is an async situation, I assumed that using a semaphore would be more appropriate than using readerwriterlocks.

Comment: @Prabhu: I'm not sure about better, but you could **not wait** for a 401 to refresh the token. Instead, refresh it every 60 minutes and serialize access only when regenerating. This implies that in `CreateRequest` you won't use `AppSettings.AccessToken` anymore, but a getter which does the job. This way you can be positive you always have the latest token. The downside is if the API changes the interval you'll have to adjust.

Comment: @Prahbu  No, it doesn't. Using the semaphore ensures only one caller can access `RefreshTokenAsync`, but they can freely access `AppSettings.AccessToken` as much as they like, even **while** the token is being updated

Comment: @MarcelN. Interesting, I never thought of proactively refreshing the token.  I think that's a good idea. I'll still need to handle the 429s because the 60 mins is not a guarantee.  Could you please elaborate on the getter?  I am not seeing how that would ensure the latest token as opposed to AppSettings.AcessToken.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov if only one caller can access RefreshTokenAsync at a time, then only one caller can update it, right? And all callers that access it the moment after it's updated should get the latest value, isn't it? Am I forgetting something basic?

Comment: But while the `RefreshTokenAsync` is executing, they're still consuming the old value.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov According to my code, all failed requests MUST go through the RefreshToken routine, and since entry to RefreshToken is serialized, all retry requests will access the latest value of AppSettings.AccessToken by the time they get to it, isn't it? I'm interested in knowing more of your thoughts because that may be the reason for my issue.

Comment: @Prabhu Consider checking the tokens validity before making the request, perhaps in `CreateRequest`. That way, the first request to encounter an expired token locks, and updates the token. That way, you save yourself the unnessacery 401

Comment: All failed request will go through your token refresh. But while the the first 401 occurs and tries to update the token, other `CreateRequest` method are running in the background and could still be consuming the old value. Should all of them refresh the token? Or is it global?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov The CreateRequest gets invoked only after awaiting RefreshToken, so I'm assuming that no CreateRequests are happening in the background when the token is being refreshed, is my assumption not correct? I'm only referring to second-time requests after the first attempt failed. My whole concern is only about retry requests having the old access token so I don't really mind if the initial first-attempt requests have the old token. But once a requestfails, I want to make sure it has the new token before it goes out the second time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is not an answer.** It's just I don't have where to post the code discussed in one of the comments.

Prabhu, I think something like this should work in order to have the token updated prior to getting a 401. This works only if you can make an assumption on how often tokens expire.

```
public HttpRequestMessage CreateRequest(string url)
{
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url);
    request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + GetUpToDateAccessToken()); 
    return request;
}

private Token GetUpToDateAccessToken()
{
    _readWriteLockSlim.EnterReadLock();
    try
    {      
        return _latestToken;
    }
    finally
    {
        _readWriteLockSlim.ExitReadLock();
    }  
}
```

Updating the token can be done with a Timer every 60 minutes. Synchronization is done with a read-write lock. This would be the Timer's tick handler (you can use a `System.Timers.Timer`).

```
private void UpdateToken()
{  
  _readWriteLockSlim.EnterWriteLock();
  try 
  {
     if ((DateTime.Now - refreshTime).TotalMinutes >= 60) 
     {
         Token newToken = GetNewToken();
         _latestToken = newToken.AccessToken;
          refreshTime = DateTime.Now;
     }
  }
  finally
  {
    _readWriteLockSlim.ExitWriteLock();
  }
}
```

As you mentioned, if the 60 minute expiry period is not guaranteed then this won't work as expected. Maybe you can re-generate the token every 5 minutes or so, to make sure you don't make requests with invalid tokens.

Finally, to handle 401s because they can still occur, you can modify the while loop in `SendRequestAsync` to:

```
if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
{
   UpdateToken();
   return await ExecuteRequestAsync(funcReq());
}
```

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov: Thanks for the edit, but I was just adding a `_readWriteLockSlim.EnterWriteLock();` where the blank line was :).

Comment: LOL, Sorry about that :)

Comment: @Marcel Thank you. Could I use this along with handling 401 in case I do get it, so that I can be sure that I don't lose any requests?

Comment: @Prabhu: If you do get a 401 then I guess you could call `UpdateToken` which enters a critical section anyway. But the weird "race condition" can still occur, less often though, if two or more requests are started before one 401s.

Comment: @MarcelN. As long as I can at least ensure that every single request made the second time will have the updated token, I don't mind the occasional race condition.

Comment: @MarcelN. Just to wrap up my thoughts around this. So, where do you think is the hole in my current code that could let a second attempt request go out with the old access token?

Comment: @Prabhu: I don't think there's ever a possibility to have a request go out at a second attempt with the old access token in your current code. There is possible, however, to have too many requests start with an expired token.

Comment: @MarcelN. it seems from my logs that there are several reattempt requests that went out with the old access token. Is something else going on?

Comment: @Prabhu: The only thing that crosses my mind now is this condition `if ((DateTime.Now - refreshTime).TotalMinutes < 60)`. If the server rejects the requests **AND** the difference is less than 60 minutes then requests will still use the old token. It's the only way.

Comment: @MarcelN. I think there is another likely scenario where that could happen. Since the refresh token logic is in a while loop, when the first batch of 401s are received, they'll be sent out with the renewed token, but if the token gets refreshed a second time before some of the retry requests go out, the "new" token they (the retry requests) have would have become stale too. Is my thinking valid?

Comment: @Prabhu: Which one was it?

Comment: @MarcelN. Another question--since this is an async scenario where I am using ConfigureAwait(false) (so the caller's context may be lost), I should really be using SemaphoreSlim for synchronization, right, rather than readerwritelocks?

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest the following workflow (added to the currently suggested from Marcel N) (pseudo code) :

```
// Manage the expiration token yourself in the Application or Db
var token = GetTokenFromDbOrApplicationWithExpirationDateTime()
// Expiration on your application can be a little bit less than real, so instead of 60 can be 50 minutes.
if (token.isExpired)
    token = RequestNewToken()
    Db.SaveChanges(token);
}

CallMethod1Async(token)
CallMethod2Async(token)
CallMethod3Async(token)
```

you also may want to check if the `CallMethodAsync` returns a response with invalid token as Marcel N provided.